# Where can I take token for discord.py?

Tags: python

im writting a modification for discord, based on discord.py. So, i saw this:

```
client.run('my token goes here')
```

Where should i take this token if i write this modification for another person?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of getting the token is via the channel settings.

Either ask the person to perform these steps, or do it yourself:

1. Start discord
2. Go to the channel you're writing the mod for
3. Click on `Edit settings` - that's the gears icon.
4. Then choose `Integrations`
5. Go to `Webhooks` and click `View Webhooks`
6. Choose a `Webhook`
7. Click `Copy Webhook URL`.

It should look like this:

`https://discord.com/api/webhooks/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/thisIsExample-Secret-g623RnPIYRAm55clPEK6w2Qqxo-zZV-IpkVsIhdwH`

Grab the string right after `/webhooks/`. That's your `Token`. Specifially, the `XXX` part is your `ID` and the rest is your bot's `Token`.

**WARNING**: Anyone who knows your Discord token has full access to your account. Do not share it with anyone!

Comment: Do you mean the part with  `XXXXXXXX` is the user discord token?